# is it possible to play FFplay video on QVideoWidget?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyqt, pyqt5, video-editing

I'm trying to build a video editing software in which before rendering we need to show the video to user so i though of using ffplay to do it and it worked for me(opening in a new window) but now i want to place in a fixed QVideoWidget so the output will be displayed their

A basic GUI image will be added below
[image]

a code to display a simple video and it works fine now i want add

```
ffplay input.mp4
```

So it plays video even editing videos

```
self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(None, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Input.mp4")
self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)))
self.player.setVideoOutput(self.widget)
self.player.play()
```

Currently, my application plays video like this in a separate window but I want to play it in that black box Hope now its a bit clear
[image]

Comment: You can embed a "foreign" window using [`createWindowContainer()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer). Besides that, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @musicamante sir I have just updated the question with 1 more image please check it once instead of ffplay playing in the new window I want it to play in that back spot Thank you

Comment: Sorry but your question still doesn't make a lot of sense. You said that you want to show the video of `ffplay` in an embedded widget, but then you also showed the code for QMediaPlayer, which is completely unrelated to that. Please try to make yourself more clear, and possibly provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @musicamante yes sir I just showed the code "QMediaPlayer" that is working with a video and now I want to do some modifications to it so it can view the ffplay video

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand. QMediaPlayer and `ffplay` are **completely unrelated**. The first is a class API that Qt uses (through the PyQt Python binding, in this case) to play some multimedia content in one of its *native* widgets, the second is **an external program** that does the same but is completely foreign to Qt and its application instance. You cannot use one "with" the other, expecially if your hope was to use QMediaPlayer to control ffplay: it's just impossible, as they are completely different object. The fact that they both can show video content is absolutely pointiless.

Comment: sorry for that @musicamante sir I thought it's possible so I asked

Comment: @musicamante sir then there is any way to add that newly opened tab to a spot in the GUI (like to be clear I don't want to open that video in a new I just wat to open somewhere in the same GUI if their is a way to do it please let me know)

Comment: I already told you in my first comment.

Comment: @musicamante sir can u please share an example for that "createWindowContainer()" thank you

Comment: Sorry, but we will not do "your homework", as it's not the scope of StackOverflow. Do some research on that function, as there are plenty of results about that. I see that you already asked other "broad" questions because you want to do things you don't fully understand yet, so I strongly suggest you to do more efforts in **studying the documentation**, experiment on your own in order to acquire more experience, and improve your research skills. Programming is about understanding how to solve problems, not asking other people to do it.

Comment: @musicamante I do agree with u but the documentation without examples is tough for me to get a clear idea as I'm new to using pyqt if there is any other resource please let me know thank you

Comment: If you're new to PyQt and you cannot understand how to do something, then you probably need to acquire more practice and experience in order to do what you want. That's the way, there are no shortcuts. People here has spent **years** studying and learning what they know. Learning is fun, as it is hard. Sorry, but I will not tell you how to do something you clearly cannot yet understand just because you're not able to properly search about it: as said, there are lots of resources on the web, this is not a coding or research service.